# How can I fix the following error?

Tags: android, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper$Callback.class

Comment: please provide the gradle structure

Comment: might be you are using similar libraries

Answer (score 1):

do you have the android-support-v4.jar in your libs folder?
If yes, then you should delete it from there, because this is by default added in the build.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...let me try it

Comment: @SrinivasNahak let me know whatever the result is

Comment: No sir after checking in lib folder I couldn't find any file like you have mentioned